# Web preview when posting on Facebook/Linkldin

Tags: html, css

I got a little issue,
when I share my portfolio in Facebook or Linkdin I get a preview of the web as an image but with a wrong image(one of the images included in the code itself).
how can I fix that so that the preview image will be the the web image?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you've already generated the image, I think you need to use this: [developers.facebook.com/tools/debug](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to rescrap it and try and get FB to pull in the correct image.

[image]

There's a section, in the screenshot, that allows you to bulk clear FB caches if it's more than one URL you're having issues with, if it's just the one, the first tab should be what you need.